# Angular Material dialog is empty when opened inside Google Maps event listener

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, dialog, angular-material

I am using Angular 6.0.6 and Angular Material 6.3.0 in the project. I've added my dialog component to `entryComponents` in the app module. The dialog works well if I open it in my dashboard component directly, but in most cases it's empty when I open it in `rightclick` event handler of a Google Maps marker.

In this case it's empty:

```
private attachEvents(wo) {
  wo.marker.addListener('rightclick', (e) => {
    this.dialog.open(DialogAlert, {
      width: '400px',
      data: {
        confirmation: true,
        message: 'test',
        title: 'X'
      }
    });
  });
}
```

If I put the `open` code outside `wo.marker.addListener` it works well.

Will be happy to hear any advice to make it working well inside the event handler. I've tried to call `detectChanges` (`ChangeDetectorRef`) inside the event handler but it doesn't help.

The dialog HTML code:

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>{{data.title ? data.title : defaultTitle}}</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <p>{{ data.message }}</p>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button *ngIf="confirmation" mat-raised-button (click)="onNoClick()">Cancel</button>

  <button *ngIf="confirmation && !options" mat-raised-button (click)="onConfirmClick()" cdkFocusInitial>Yes</button>
  <button color="primary" *ngFor="let o of options;  index as i" mat-raised-button (click)="onConfirmClick(i)">{{o}}</button>

  <button *ngIf="!confirmation" mat-raised-button (click)="onConfirmClick()" cdkFocusInitial>OK</button>
</div>
```

If I put in the HTML something at the beginning (outside `mat-dialog-title`, `mat-dialog-content`, `mat-dialog-actions`) it will be displayed.

And some more info:

- No errors/warnings in console.
- I can't close the dialog by click on the shadow area. (I can when it is not empty)
- In very rare cases the content is shown, sometimes with a minor delay.
- When the empty dialog is opened and I resize browser window the content appears.
- I test it in the recent version of Google Chrome

Comment: Could you add a stackblitz or JSFiddle? I try it using the agm library https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps and works fine.

Comment: Try entering ngZone through `zone.run(`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@yurzui comment helped. Thanks a lot! So the solution is:

> Try entering ngZone through zone.run(

So in my example the things that should be changed:

1. Add `private zone: NgZone` to the component constructor.
2. Open dialog through `zone.run(`.

The example function looks like this now:

```
private attachEvents(wo) {
  wo.marker.addListener('rightclick', (e) => {
    this.zone.run(() => {
      this.dialog.open(DialogAlert, {
        width: '400px',
        data: {
          confirmation: true,
          message: 'test',
          title: 'X'
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```

PS. My real code is slightly different but the flow and idea is the same. By this, I want to say that I didn't run the code that is posted above so if you copy and paste it somewhere it might not work.